Remove duplicates from search with STRING_AGG
I would like to remove duplicates when aggregating results using string_agg in SQL server. I have tried a few methods in SO but they don't seem to work
this is the structure of my table,
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=65d04783-2b98-4e3d-acb1-b045d118f18a



SubscriptionId
Number
BusinessOwner
ResourceGroupName
ITApplicationOwner
Parent




a1b2c3d4-1234-5678-9abc-123456789abc
AP000000001
John Doe
rg-xyz-abc-123-usw-01
Jane Smith
Global Tech Corp (TECH)


a1b2c3d4-1234-5678-9abc-123456789abc
AP000000002
John Doe
rg-xyz-abc-123-usw-01
Alan Brown
Global Tech Corp (TECH)


a1b2c3d4-1234-5678-9abc-123456789abc
AP000000003
Maria Johnson
rg-xyz-abc-123-usw-01
David Clark
Global Tech Corp (TECH)



and I want it to output as follows,



SubscriptionId
Number
BusinessOwner
ResourceGroupName
ITApplicationOwner
Parent




a1b2c3d4-1234-5678-9abc-123456789abc
AP000000001,AP000000002,AP000000003
John Doe, Maria Johnson
rg-xyz-abc-123-usw-01
Jane Smith, Alan Brown, David Clark
Global Tech Corp (TECH)



This is my current query in SQL which adds the values in the required format but does not remove duplicates,
    WITH CombinedData AS (
    SELECT 
        tmo.SubscriptionId,
        tmo.ResourceGroupName,

        -- Removing duplicates in the Numbers field
        (SELECT STRING_AGG( tmo2.Number, ',') 
         FROM [TRFM_multipleappid-owners] tmo2
         WHERE tmo2.SubscriptionId = tmo.SubscriptionId 
         AND tmo2.ResourceGroupName = tmo.ResourceGroupName) AS Numbers,
        
        -- Removing duplicates in the BusinessOwners field
        (SELECT STRING_AGG( tmo2.BusinessOwner, ',') 
         FROM [TRFM_multipleappid-owners] tmo2
         WHERE tmo2.SubscriptionId = tmo.SubscriptionId 
         AND tmo2.ResourceGroupName = tmo.ResourceGroupName) AS BusinessOwners,
        
        -- Removing duplicates in the ITApplicationOwner field
        (SELECT  STRING_AGG( tmo2.ITApplicationOwner, ',') 
         FROM [TRFM_multipleappid-owners] tmo2
         WHERE tmo2.SubscriptionId = tmo.SubscriptionId 
         AND tmo2.ResourceGroupName = tmo.ResourceGroupName) AS ITApplicationOwners,
        
        -- Removing duplicates in the Parents field
        (SELECT STRING_AGG( tmo2.parent, ',') 
         FROM [TRFM_multipleappid-owners] tmo2
         WHERE tmo2.SubscriptionId = tmo.SubscriptionId 
         AND tmo2.ResourceGroupName = tmo.ResourceGroupName) AS Parents
         
    FROM 
        [TRFM_multipleappid-owners] tmo
    GROUP BY 
        tmo.SubscriptionId, 
        tmo.ResourceGroupName
)

SELECT 
    CombinedData.SubscriptionId,
    CombinedData.Numbers,
    CombinedData.BusinessOwners,
    CombinedData.ResourceGroupName,
    CombinedData.ITApplicationOwners,
    CombinedData.Parents
FROM 
    CombinedData;

how do I go about removing duplicates in the fields ?

Have you tried using DISTINCT inside each select? Example (SELECT DISTINCT STRING_AGG( tmo2.Number, ',')           FROM [TRFM_multipleappid-owners] tmo2          WHERE tmo2.SubscriptionId = tmo.SubscriptionId           AND tmo2.ResourceGroupName = tmo.ResourceGroupName) AS Numbers

they are using a cross apply - which is why it is different

Where the subquery is isn't relevant, @rusty009 , the solution is the same.

Remember to upvote on Microsoft adding DISTINCT to STRING_AGG https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/0e8fa860-7c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

ok, I have spent time looking at the answer and have found a solution. the problem is that the solutions don't clearly explain what they've done, they just solve the specific problem for these people. can you re-open the question and I will answer myself and make the answer more clear
